# error: command 'c:\\mingw\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, windows-8.1

I've been experiencing the "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" error in Pycharm when installing third-party packages using Easy_install.

Once installed the MinGW, checked that gcc compiler is marked, configured the distutils.cfg, and changed the PATH variable, I find the following problem:

```
Install packages failed: Error occurred when installing package pysqlite. 

The following command was executed:

packaging_tool.py install --build-dir C:\Users\Francisco\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-    packaging5564903716757323670.tmp pysqlite

The error output of the command:


Downloading/unpacking pysqlite
Running setup.py egg_info for package pysqlite

Installing collected packages: pysqlite
  Running setup.py install for pysqlite
    building 'pysqlite2._sqlite' extension
    c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlite2.dbapi2\" -    DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c src/module.c -o   build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\module.o
In file included from src/module.c:24:
src/connection.h:33:21: error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
In file included from src/module.c:24:
src/connection.h:38: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sqlite3'
In file included from src/module.c:25:
src/statement.h:37: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sqlite3'
src/module.c: In function 'module_complete':
src/module.c:103: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sqlite3_complete'
src/module.c: At top level:
src/module.c:269: error: 'SQLITE_OK' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:270: error: 'SQLITE_DENY' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:271: error: 'SQLITE_IGNORE' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:272: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_INDEX' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:273: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_TABLE' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:274: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_INDEX' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:275: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_TABLE' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:276: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_TRIGGER' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:277: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_VIEW' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:278: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_TRIGGER' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:279: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_VIEW' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:280: error: 'SQLITE_DELETE' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:281: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_INDEX' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:282: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_TABLE' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:283: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_INDEX' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:284: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_TABLE' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:285: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_TRIGGER' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:286: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_VIEW' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:287: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_TRIGGER' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:288: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_VIEW' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:289: error: 'SQLITE_INSERT' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:290: error: 'SQLITE_PRAGMA' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:291: error: 'SQLITE_READ' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:292: error: 'SQLITE_SELECT' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:293: error: 'SQLITE_TRANSACTION' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:294: error: 'SQLITE_UPDATE' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:295: error: 'SQLITE_ATTACH' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c:296: error: 'SQLITE_DETACH' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/module.c: In function 'init_sqlite':
src/module.c:426: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sqlite3_libversion'
src/module.c:426: warning: passing argument 1 of 'PyString_FromString' makes pointer from integer without a cast
error: command 'c:\\mingw\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import  setuptools;__file__='C:\\Users\\Francisco\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm- packaging5564903716757323670.tmp\\pysqlite\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\franci~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-obw3c6-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win32-2.7

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2

copying lib\dbapi2.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2

copying lib\dump.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2

copying lib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test

copying lib\test\dbapi.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test

copying lib\test\dump.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test

copying lib\test\factory.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test

copying lib\test\hooks.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test

copying lib\test\regression.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test

copying lib\test\transactions.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test

copying lib\test\types.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test

copying lib\test\userfunctions.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test

copying lib\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test\py25

copying lib\test\py25\py25tests.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test\py25

copying lib\test\py25\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pysqlite2\test\py25

running build_ext

building 'pysqlite2._sqlite' extension

creating build\temp.win32-2.7

creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release

creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src

c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlite2.dbapi2\" -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c src/module.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\module.o

In file included from src/module.c:24:

src/connection.h:33:21: error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory

In file included from src/module.c:24:

src/connection.h:38: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sqlite3'

In file included from src/module.c:25:

src/statement.h:37: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sqlite3'

src/module.c: In function 'module_complete':

src/module.c:103: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sqlite3_complete'

src/module.c: At top level:

src/module.c:269: error: 'SQLITE_OK' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:270: error: 'SQLITE_DENY' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:271: error: 'SQLITE_IGNORE' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:272: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_INDEX' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:273: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_TABLE' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:274: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_INDEX' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:275: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_TABLE' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:276: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_TRIGGER' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:277: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_VIEW' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:278: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_TRIGGER' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:279: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_VIEW' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:280: error: 'SQLITE_DELETE' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:281: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_INDEX' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:282: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_TABLE' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:283: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_INDEX' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:284: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_TABLE' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:285: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_TRIGGER' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:286: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_VIEW' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:287: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_TRIGGER' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:288: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_VIEW' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:289: error: 'SQLITE_INSERT' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:290: error: 'SQLITE_PRAGMA' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:291: error: 'SQLITE_READ' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:292: error: 'SQLITE_SELECT' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:293: error: 'SQLITE_TRANSACTION' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:294: error: 'SQLITE_UPDATE' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:295: error: 'SQLITE_ATTACH' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c:296: error: 'SQLITE_DETACH' undeclared here (not in a function)

src/module.c: In function 'init_sqlite':

src/module.c:426: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sqlite3_libversion'

src/module.c:426: warning: passing argument 1 of 'PyString_FromString' makes pointer       from integer without a cast

error: command 'c:\\mingw\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm working over Windows 8. Maybe the problem is in the *.h files from python. Any idea?

Comment: Why are you installing `pysqlite`? SQLite compatibility is included in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key error is this one

```
 src/connection.h:33:21: error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
```

You don't have the sqlite3 header files so it can compile the extension. The MinGW compiler seems to be working ok.

You need to download [the source code](http://sqlite.org), build it and make it available to easy_install, and the same with the rest of the dependencies.

However, I wonder why you need to install pysqlite when you already have the `sqlite3` module included as part of the standard windows Python distribution. Just enter the interpreter and issue an `import sqlite3` command.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I don't know how to do it but I will manage somehow to solve it. Answering to your question: I need to upgrade the sqlite3 version since it isn't able to open some specific DB. It just say that the sqlite file is corrupted or encrypted. Moreover I'm trying to install it trough the PyCharm Package installing interface but it always gives the aforementioned error.

Comment: If the database is encrypted make sure this PySqlite module you are building supports the encryption extension. I believe (but may be wrong) that PySqlite is just the same sqlite3 built-in module kept around to be compiled for _very old_ versions of python if needed. Also, if you are satisfied with the response, it is good StackOverflow manners to accept it.

Comment: Is not a encryptation problem at all since I'm able to open it from sqlite3 command line. Cheers.